# PHP 7.4 Trying to access array offset

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using this code but now I am getting an error message in my debug log:

Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
$my_image = ( $image[0] != '' ) ? '' . $image[0] . '' : '""';
```

I believe the problem relates to PHP 7.4 which I am now using?

Comment: If `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` fails there's no point in continuing the program flow as if nothing had happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described on the WordPress [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/#return) `wp_get_attachment_image_src` may return false if no image is available. As the error says you are trying to access the return value always as an array, but it might be a `bool` (`false`).
Try this:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
$my_image = $image !== false ? '' . $image[0] . '' : '""';
```

Answer (score 1):

`wp_get_attachment_image_src` is returning a bool (false in your case) instead of an array, as your image probably doesn't exist.

Make sure to check `$my_image` before trying to access the array:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' );
if (image) {
     $my_image = ( $image[0] != '' ) ? '' . $image[0] . '' : '""';
}
```

The documentation states :

> Return
>
> (array|false) Array of image data, or boolean false if no image is
> available.
>
> - (string) Image source URL.
> - '1'
>
> (int) Image width in pixels.
>
> - '2'
>
> (int) Image height in pixels.
>
> - '3'
>
> (bool) Whether the image is a resized image.

Source: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/